# Why does "conformsToProtocol" not check for "required" method implementations?

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, protocols

I am trying to enforce a "formal" `@protocol`, but cannot reliably test my classes/instances as to whether they ACTUALLY implement the protocol's "required" methods, vs. simply "declaring" that they conform to the protocol.

A complete example of my quandary…

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol       RequiredProtocol 
@required                   
- (NSString*) mustImplement;                              @end 
@interface      Cog         : NSObject <RequiredProtocol> @end
@implementation Cog                                       @end
@interface      Sprocket    : NSObject                    @end 
@implementation Sprocket 
- (NSString*) mustImplement
  { return @"I conform, but ObjC doesn't care!"; }        @end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Protocol *required = @protocol(RequiredProtocol);
    SEL    requiredSEL = @selector(mustImplement);
    void (^testProtocolConformance)(NSObject*) = ^(NSObject *x){
        NSLog(@"Protocol:%@\n"
               "Does %@ class conform:%@     \n"
               "Do  instances conform:%@     \n"
               "Required method's result:\"%@\"", 
        NSStringFromProtocol ( required ),
        NSStringFromClass    ( x.class  ), 
        [x.class conformsToProtocol:required] ? @"YES" : @"NO", 
        [x       conformsToProtocol:required] ? @"YES" : @"NO",
        [x    respondsToSelector:requiredSEL] ? [x mustImplement]
                                              : nil );
    };
    testProtocolConformance ( Cog.new      );
    testProtocolConformance ( Sprocket.new );
}
```

Result:

```
Protocol:RequiredProtocol
Does Cog class conform:YES
Do instances conform:YES
Required method's result:"(null)"

Protocol:RequiredProtocol
Does Sprocket class conform:NO
Do instances conform:NO
Required method's result:"I conform, but ObjC doesn't care!"
```

Why is it that a class and it's instances that DO implement the `@protocol`'s methods (`Sprocket`) return `NO` to `conformsToProtocol`?

And why does one that DOESN'T ACTUALLY conform, but SAYS that it DOES (`Cog`) return `YES`?

What is the point of a *formal protocol* if the declaration is all that's needed to feign conformance?

How can you ACTUALLY check for complete implementation of multiple `@selector`s without MULTIPLE calls to `respondsToSelector`?

@Josh Caswell.. Without `diff`ing the two.. I'd guess that your response achieves similar effect to the category on `NSObject` I've been using in the meantime…

```
@implementation NSObject (ProtocolConformance)
- (BOOL) implementsProtocol:(id)nameOrProtocol {
   Protocol *p = [nameOrProtocol isKindOfClass:NSString.class] 
               ? NSProtocolFromString(nameOrProtocol) 
               : nameOrProtocol;  // Arg is string OR protocol
   Class klass = self.class;
   unsigned int outCount = 0;
   struct objc_method_description *methods = NULL;
   methods = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList( p, YES, YES, &outCount);
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < outCount; ++i) {
       SEL selector = methods[i].name;
       if (![klass instancesRespondToSelector: selector]) {
           if (methods) free(methods); methods = NULL; return NO;
       }
    }
    if (methods) free(methods); methods = NULL; return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: if a class doesn't implement a required method, you will get a warning... that is a programming error;

Comment: That is some downright funky code formatting....

Comment: tl;dr The compiler checks protocol conformance.  Take a zero warning/error policy and you'll know the classes conform to the protocol(s).   Checking at runtime would be redundant, potentially slow, and run in an unpredictable amount of time.

Comment: @bbum The formatting is a bit contrived - to eliminate "scrolling", aka cutting me off.  @Grady Player Thank you!  I thought I was going nuts… but your emphasis made me look - and realize - that I had inserted `-w` into my `Code Runner` compile script.  Duh.

Answer (score 9):

Conforming to a protocol is just a "promise", you can't know if the receiver of *conformsToProtocol:* actually implements all the required methods. Is enough that you declare that the class conforms to the protocol using the angle brackets syntax, and *conformsToProtocol:* will return yes:

> Discussion
>   A class is said to “conform to” a protocol if it adopts the protocol or inherits from another class that adopts it. Protocols are adopted by listing them within angle brackets after the interface declaration.

Full source: [*NSObject's conformsToProtocol:*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol%3a) .

Protocols declarations have just the advantage that you can know **at compile time** if a class really adopts that required methods. If not, a warning will be given. I suggest to don't rely on *conformsToProtocol:*, but to use introspection instead. That is, verify if a class/object implements a method by calling *instancesRespondToSelector:* / *respondsToSelector:* :

```
+ (BOOL)instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
```

Answer (score 4):

What compiler are you using? Xcode/Clang issues 2 warnings and 1 error...

Think of a protocol as a club with membership requirements. Asking whether someone is a member of the club, provable by them having a membership card (`NSObject<ReqiredProtocol>`), should tell you that a person meets those requirements. However the lack of a membership doesn't mean they don't meet the requirements.

E.g. someone (`Sprocket`) might meet all the requirements to join but choose not to. Someone else (`Cog`) may failed to meet the requirements but a sloppy administrator might let them in.

The latter is why I asked about the compiler (the sloppy administrator ;-)). Try your code as entered on Xcode 4.6.3/Clang 4.2 produces warnings and errors (as does using GCC 4.2):

1. The warnings state that `Cog` fails to implement the required methods;
2. The error complains about `[x mustImplement]` as `x` is not known to have the required method as it is of type `NSObject` - you need to cast to remove that, just `[(id)x mustImplement]` will do as you've already tested the method exists.

In summary, you can only rely on `conformsToProtocol` if you know the originator of the code didn't ignore compiler warnings - the checking is done at compile time.

**Addendum**

I missed the last sentence of your question. If you wish to discover whether a class meets the requirements of a protocol, even if it doesn't declare that it does, e.g. `Sprocket` above (or if you are obtaining code from folk who ignore compiler warnings - the `Cog` author above), then you can do so using the facilities of the Obj-C runtime. And you'll only have to *write* one call to `repsondsToSelector`...

I just typed in the following and quickly tested it on your sample. It is **not throughly tested** by any means, *caveat emptor* etc. Code assumes ARC.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface ProtocolChecker : NSObject

+ (BOOL) doesClass:(Class)aClass meetTheRequirementsOf:(Protocol *)aProtocol;

@end

@implementation ProtocolChecker

+ (BOOL) doesClass:(Class)aClass meetTheRequirementsOf:(Protocol *)aProtocol
{

   struct objc_method_description *methods;
   unsigned int count;

   // required instance methods
   methods = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(aProtocol, YES, YES, &count);
   for (unsigned int ix = 0; ix < count; ix++)
   {
      if (![aClass instancesRespondToSelector:methods[ix].name])
      {
         free(methods);
         return NO;
      }
   }
   free(methods);

   // required class methods
   methods = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(aProtocol, YES, NO, &count);
   for (unsigned int ix = 0; ix < count; ix++)
   {
      if (![aClass respondsToSelector:methods[ix].name])
      {
         free(methods);
         return NO;
      }
   }
   free(methods);

   // other protocols
   Protocol * __unsafe_unretained *protocols = protocol_copyProtocolList(aProtocol, &count);
   for (unsigned int ix = 0; ix < count; ix++)
   {
      if (![self doesClass:aClass meetTheRequirementsOf:protocols[ix]])
      {
         free(protocols);
         return NO;
      }
   }
   free(protocols);

   return YES;
}

@end
```

You should of course want to know exactly how this works, especially the `* __unsafe_unretained *` bit. That is left as an exercise :-)

Comment: This is it. Each class keeps a list of the protocols to which it says it conforms, and it's that list (as well as superclasses' lists) that `conformsToProtocol:` checks. The actual conformance check -- are these promised methods implemented -- is _only_ performed at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

CRD is right; the compiler tells you about *actual* conformance, and it should be listened to. If that's being ignored, the runtime doesn't have any built-in method to double-check. Classes maintain internal lists of protocol objects internally; `conformsToProtocol:` just looks at that.

At the risk that someone is going to come along and tell me to stop fiddling with the #@(%!^& runtime again, if you really truly need to check *actual* implementation, this is one way you can do so:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

BOOL classReallyTrulyDoesImplementAllTheRequiredMethodsOfThisProtocol(Class cls, Protocol * prtcl)
{
    unsigned int meth_count;
    struct objc_method_description * meth_list;
    meth_list = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(p, 
                                                   YES /*isRequired*/,
                                                   YES /*isInstanceMethod*/,
                                                   &meth_count);
    /* Check instance methods */ 
    for(int i = 0; i < meth_count; i++ ){
        SEL methName = meth_list[i].name;
        if( ![class instancesRespondToSelector:methName] ){
            /* Missing _any_ required methods means failure */ 
            free(meth_list);
            return NO;
        }
    }
    free(meth_list);

    meth_list = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(p, 
                                                   YES /*isRequired*/,
                                                   NO /*isInstanceMethod*/,
                                                   &meth_count);
    /* Check class methods, if any */
    for(int i = 0; i < meth_count; i++ ){
        SEL methName = meth_list[i].name;
        if( ![class respondsToSelector:methName] ){
            free(meth_list);
            return NO;
        }
    }
    free(meth_list);                          

    return YES;
}
```

<sub>*If I had a hammer...*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers are good.  To them, I would add one more point: calling `conformsToProtocol:` is almost always a mistake.  Because it tells whether the class says that it conforms to the protocol, rather than whether it actually provides specific methods:

- It is possible to create a class that claims to conform, but does not, by silencing various warnings, resulting in crashes if you assume that a required method exists.
- It is possible to create a class that conforms to the protocol but does not claim to do so, resulting in methods not getting called on a delegate even though they exist.
- It can lead to programming errors creeping in when the protocol changes, because your code checks for conformance to a protocol before calling a method that used to be required, but no longer is.

All of these issues can cause unexpected behavior.

IMO, if you want to know if a class handles a method, the safest approach is to explicitly ask it if it handles that method (`respondsToSelector:`), rather than asking it if it conforms to a protocol that just happens to contain that method.

IMO, `conformsToProtocol:` should really have been a function in the Objective-C runtime instead of being exposed on NSObject, because it generally causes more problems than it solves.