# conformsToProtocol doesn't work

Tags: objective-c

Hi I have a problem with one protocol

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  @protocol StandardQuality <NSObject>

  - (NSString *)color;
  - (NSString *)fabric;
  -( NSString *)store;
  - ( NSString *)price;

  @end
```

I implement this protocol in a class

```
  @interface Hat : NSObject <StandardQuality> 

  @property NSString *color;
  @property NSString *fabric;
  @property NSString *store;

  @end
```

It is happens what I expected . I received a warning message

method "price" in protocol not implemented.

Anyway.I tested in main.h

```
    [myHat setShop:@"Unirea"];
    NSLog(@" The  hat is selling at %@", myHat.store);

    if([myHat conformsToProtocol:@protocol(StandardQuality)]== YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"My hat respects the protocol");
    }
    else {
         NSLog(@"My hat doesn't respect the protocol");

    }


    if([myHat respondsToSelector:@selector(price)]== YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"My hat has price");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"My hat doesn't have price");

    }
```

Strangely, I recieved

My hat respects the protocol

My hat doesn't have price

My second question is : It is a way to block the compiler to compile your program if a protocol is not respected , not just to receive a warning message?

Answer (score 2):

> Strangely, I recieved
>
> My hat respects the protocol
>
> My hat doesn't have price

What's strange? You get back exactly what you did. Your class conforms to the protocol, but doesn't implement the `price` method.

> It is a way to block the compiler to compile your program if a protocol is not respected , not just to receive a warning message?

I assume you wanted to ask if there is a way. Well, you can turn on the `-Werr` compiler switch which makes the compiler bail out if a warning is encountered, then possibly turn off warnings only for unimplemented methods in a protocol (google for the appropriate compiler flag).

Comment: I thought if a class  conforms to the protocol must implement all protocol's methods.

Comment: @JohnJohnny No. (Well, it *should,* but it doesn't mean that if it doesn't, then the compiler won't generate the info about protocol conformance into the class.)

Comment: It is a method to test the protocol conformance into the class?

Comment: A way to test if a class respects a protocol

Comment: @JohnJohnny `if ([TheClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)])`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. What I want is that the compiler to generate the info about protocol conformance into the class.

Comment: But you gave me what I already have in my code. It is a circular discusion

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the warning for an incomplete protocol into an error by adding `-Werror=incomplete-implementation` to the "Other C Flags" in the "Language" section of your Xcode projects "Build Settings" (or you can pass that option to the compiler if invoking from the command line).

If you'd like to check at runtime whether a class actually implements a protocol, as opposed to simply declaring that it does, see [addendum to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820466/why-does-conformstoprotocol-not-check-for-required-method-implementations/16821404#16821404).

Answer (score 1):

From the [API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol%3a):

> This method determines conformance solely on the basis of the formal
>   declarations in header files, as illustrated above. It doesn’t check
>   to see whether the methods declared in the protocol are actually
>   implemented—that’s the programmer’s responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol%3a) your class conforms to the protocol because you are declaring it as such in it's `@interface`

```
@interface Hat : NSObject <StandardQuality>
```

However, you haven't implemented the `price` method.

There is the concept of `@required` and `@optional` protocol methods. If you absolutely require an class to implement all or some of the methods of a protocol you should specify it like this:

```
@protocol StandardQuality <NSObject>

@required
- (NSString *)color;
- (NSString *)fabric;
- (NSString *)store;

@optional
- (NSString *)price;

@end
```

In which case you should check that the object implementing a protocol actually implements the optional methods without calling them.

I think is more what you are looking for.